# Sql Server logs, how to see whos removing access

Tags: sql-server, security

We are having an issue where access from a security account keeps getting removed to a database.  How or where do you check the logs to see who keeps removing access to a specific account that has access to a specific database?

Comment: better to post on DBA: http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Note that SQL server logs might not be sufficient, if the user is using sp_password in the query it will not add the query to the logs due to the nature of the stored proc.